# Cross-Object SOQL without Relationships?

Tags: apex, soql, custom-object

I have 3 objects. 
A conversation object for conversations between the user and a lead/account/contact.
A tag object to allow the user to categorize conversations.
And a conversation-tag object which has 2 fields, a Conversation ID and a Tag ID, to facilitate the many to many relationship between the two.

What I am looking to do is create a query that fetches all tags under a conversation with the name of the tag as well.

The query I tried to write looked like this, but this doesn't seem to work.

```
SELECT c.Id, c.ConversationID__c, c.TagID__c, t.TagName FROM ConversationTagRelation__c c, Tag__c t WHERE c.TagID__c = t.Id
```

Comment: What is the relationship between Conversion and Tag? If any, who is the child?

Comment: @Viasur No child, a Conversation can be linked to multiple Tags, and a Tag can be linked to multiple Conversations.

Answer (score 0):

If I understand correctly Conversion tag is the junction between conversion and Tag. so you can write query like

```
List<ConversationTagRelation__c > ctList = [select id, tagId__c,tagId__r.Name,conversionId__c 
                                              from ConversationTagRelation__c  
                                              where ConversationId__c IN : conversionIdset 
                                              Order By ConversationId__c]
```

and you will get Conversation and related tags.

Comment: Well my goal is not just to get a conversation and related tags, but to fetch the tag Name for the related tags as well, which is where I'm running into issues. 
Please refer to my SOQL above.

Comment: @JasonLee check my updated answer.